# Query by date to mysql database

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to query to database using date field. But it is returning null set. The date field in my database is like `2012-05-16 00:00:00`.

```
String alDate = getStringParam(dataMap, "dt_" + i + j);
Date startdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss").parse(alDate);
```

Where value of alDate is the date string coming from JSP page. But when I query with "startdate" either throws error or returns null set. Any suggestions?

HOw do i know if data exists for a specific date? I have passed the date object in hibernate criteria to find. It works but sometimes it fails.

Comment: what's the query? should i+j be an item, as in (i+j)?

Comment: Please provide the surrounding code, otherwise any answers you do actually receive will be vague.

Comment: mcfinnigan- edited the question. query is a hibernate query. It takes the startdate as parameter.

Comment: Are you getting hh:MM:ss also from JSP input string.  Are you really sure you want to compare date columns along with time?

Comment: What error did throw? what is the correct data type of your date column? A `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 0):

The [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is wrong :

- Capital 'M' for month, little 'm' for minute.
- Capital 'H' for hour

For example :

```
startdate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: But after parsing it is showing the date as "Wed May 16 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012". So my query is not properly executed

Comment: @Cyphon use **SimpleDateFormat#parse(String)** to convert String -> Date and **SimpleDateFormat#format(Date)** to convert Date -> String. *"Wed May 16 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012"* is the output from **Date#toString()**, so you will need to convert your Date back to String using **format(Date)**.

Comment: but i want it as date. Because I need to query using date type object and not string type.

Comment: @Cyphon SQL statements are Strings not Objects. If you are using JPA you need to show more code in your question.

Comment: It is a hibernate query using criteria. It takes date object

Comment: @Cyphon *"It is a hibernate query using criteria. It takes date object"* This is the code that you need to show us.